# Is "The thinking of humanity needs oil to survive is completely wrong" a correct senetence?

Tags: prepositions, subjects

I am practicing for the IELTS test and end up freezing at the moment wondering whether the above structure correct: "The thinking of.." followed by a full statement as the subject and then "...is completely wrong". It sounded right to me but I couldn't find any example online with that structure. Hope you guys can help. Thanks!

Comment: It's fine grammatically, conveying that *it's wrong to say that the survival of "the thinking of humanity" requires oil*. But ... why is oil needed for "the thinking of humanity" to survive? If you're referring to oils (e.g. fish oil?) needed for brain function, perhaps. If you're trying to say that "humanity needs (mineral) oil", you're better off rephrasing.

Comment: Lawrence, I believe the phrase is meant to mean that the belief that humanity needs oil (as in the fossil fuel) needs to end.

Comment: Also, I think the sentence should read, "The thinking *that* humanity..." But I'm not putting it as an answer, because I can't for the life of me think of a way to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatically incorrect:

> "**The thinking of humanity** needs **oil to survive** is completely wrong."

Using the preposition *of* makes "the thinking of humanity" into a noun phrase, which is then followed by the verb phrase "needs oil to survive" and the sentence fragment "is completely wrong."

What you really want to do is relate "the thinking" and "humanity needs oil" with the complementizer *that*:

> "**The thinking** *that* **humanity needs oil to survive** is completely wrong."

(You could also use "The thought that... ", "The idea that ...", or "The belief that ..." to convey essentially the same thing.)

In the above sentence structure, the word *that* functions as a complementizer, clarifying what "the thinking" is:

> "The thinking is completely wrong."

*What thinking is completely wrong?*

> "The thinking *that* **humanity needs oil to survive** is completely wrong."